# Do Kotlin Sequences cache intermediate results?

Tags: scala, kotlin, stream, lazy-sequences, scala-streams

When operating Kotlin sequences with functional APIs such as `map`, `flatMap`, `+`, etc., are computed intermediate results cached so upon second evaluation there is no recomputation?

If not, replacing `List`s with `Sequence`s could in some situations cause complexity to blow up exponentially, and the word "lazy" used in [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html) seems not precise enough to distinguish the two behaviors.

In other words, comparing to Scala, are Kotlin `Sequence`s more like Scala `Stream`s/`LazyList`s (where "Once computed, a value stays computed and is reused. Or, as you say, the values are cached.") or `View`s (where "all transformations are re-applied each time you need to fetch elements from it")? (quoted content from [What is the difference between view, stream and iterator? | FAQ | Scala Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/stream-view-iterator.html))

Comment: Sequences in Kotlin are similar in design to streams in Java. You create a sequence of operations to perform then, upon a terminal operation, the entire sequence is evaluated for each element in the source. Sequences are, I believe, single-use just like Java streams.

Comment: @Slaw Sequences can be used multiple times and their elements are re-evaluated on each use.

Comment: @Slaw You're welcome. I learned that the hard way, because one of the sequence steps was performing file I/O. This caused heavy performance drops as the I/O step was executed repeatedly. I suppose that's a typical example for a bad use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is re-evaluated every time you call a terminal function on it. But you can evaluate it with `toList()` to complete the evaluation one time and use the list for subsequent operations.

Comment: Not if the sequence is infinite, you can't. :)